# Find repeated words with grep/egrep

Tags: grep, words, repeat

I need to find repeated words with grep/egrep. The scheme is the following:

space word1<1 or more spaces>word1<2 or more spaces>word2<1 or more spaces>word2 space

**Example**

hello world  world   yaaay   yaaay abc

**After grep:** " world  world   yaaay   yaaay "

I tried to use: `egrep " (\w{1,}) {1,}\1 "`

Comment: have you tried my answer?

Comment: Yes, I tried! Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can achive this with `awk`:

```
echo "hello world world yaaay yaaay abc" | awk 'BEGIN{tmp=""; result=""} {for(x=1;x<=NF;x++){if($x==tmp){result = result " "  $x " " $x};tmp=$x}} END{print result}'
```

Output:

```
 world world yaaay yaaay
```

One more test with string "hello world world yaaay yaaay wow aaa aaa abc":

```
echo "hello world world yaaay yaaay wow aaa aaa abc" | awk 'BEGIN{tmp=""; result=""} {for(x=1;x<=NF;x++){if($x==tmp){result = result " "  $x " " $x};tmp=$x}} END{print result}'
```

Output:

world world yaaay yaaay aaa aaa